# Does Solidity include all code of parent (base) contract in child contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design

Suppose I've two contracts `animal` and `dog`, and lets say that:

```
contract dog is animal {
...
}
```

Does `dog` include ALL code of `animal`, or just the code that it uses?

What if `dog` uses only a few function of `animal`? How do I make Solidity skip the other "unused" functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Inheritance part of the Solidity documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/contracts.html#inheritance), it states that

> When a contract inherits from multiple contracts, only a single
>   contract is created on the blockchain, and the code from all the base
>   contracts is copied into the created contract.

In your case all **non-private(public and internal)** members and functions of animal contract will be copied into dog contract.

Comment: What about private functions?

Comment: Private functions and state variables are only visible for the contract they are defined in and not in derived contracts.

Comment: But they are still present in the derived contract? Part of its code?

Comment: @Shuzheng have you found an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Dog will include all of the variables and functions within animal.

If you only want to use certain functions you could just break up the base interface into different contracts so that you can use them at your discretion.